# Drawing traffic light, Error in passing of variables I think

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I'm trying to  fill each circle with a colour. The paintComponent method is supposed to create the general outline of a traffic light.
Then the other methods are supposed to fill each circle with a different color, depending on what color the traffic light is going to be. I get the error, that it cant find symbol( e.g

> TrafficLight.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
>         g2.fill(circle3);

I didnt think I had to pass the circle variables into the other methods, if they were in the same class. I tried adding the circle variables and then i get identifier expected. Pretty sure there's something about the passing of variables that im not getting, but any help would be appreciated

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TrafficLight extends JComponent
{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;

    Rectangle box= new Rectangle(100,800,200,700);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fill(box);   
    g2.draw(box);   

    Ellipse2D.Double circle1=new Ellipse2D.Double(200,200,200,200);
    g2.draw(circle1);

    Ellipse2D.Double circle2=new Ellipse2D.Double(200,200,200,400);
    g2.draw(circle2);

    Ellipse2D.Double circle3=new Ellipse2D.Double(200,200,200,600);
    g2.draw(circle3);
}

public void drawRed(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2=(Grpahics2D) g;       

    g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(circle1);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fill(circle2);
    g2.fill(circle3);
}

public void drawGreen(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
    g2.fill(circle3);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fill(circle2);
    g2.fill(circle1);
}

public void drawYellow(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setPaint(Color.YELLOW);
    g2.fill(circle2);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fill(circle1);
    g2.fill(circle3);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The entire code is missing.
But the general solution is to have the paintComponent method do all.
So have a state red/green/yellow.

```
public class TrafficLight extends JComponent {

    public enum Light { RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLACK }

    private Light light = Light.BLACK;

    public void setLight(Light light) {
        this.light = light;
        repaint(50L); // Repaint almost immediately.
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        ...
        // Draw red bulb
        g2.setPaint(light == Light.RED ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
        ...
        // Draw yellow bulb
        g2.setPaint(light == Light.YELLOW ? Color.YELLOW : Color.BLACK);
        ...
        // Draw green bulb
        g2.setPaint(light == Light.GREEN ? Color.GREEN : Color.BLACK);
```

Switching the light then alters the state and causes a repaint. There are some repaint methods.

Instead of the enum one might use `Color light;`, but that is not so clear.
Also consider an enum value BLACK, for semaphores without electricity.

To handle automatic timed switching, one might use a *swing* `Timer`.